# SpeechRecognitionEngine does not change CultureInfo

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cultureinfo

Good day,

I know that there is a lot of info about that topic out there, but i promise i try a lot of them and none of them worked for this specific problem.
Tho i actually manage to make my app work, but it does not work properly.

I am building a service that will take audio file in one place listen it and send an email to the proper responsible.

The thing is that it don't want to use our local CultureInfo which is fr-CA. It stick to fr-FR. I have the feeling that the quality of the reading would be better if it would use our cultureInfo.

All my work by now come from the offical documentation
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine?view=netframework-4.8.1)
and
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtowavefile?view=netframework-4.8.1).

I had to tweak it a little to make it work with fr-FR.
By now, the code "work" but mostly give me gibberish if i don't speak clearly in front of the mic. I looked at my computer parameters and fr-CA seems to be set everywhere.

Any tip (or link to formation) to improve speak recognition on .wav file would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for any help.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Speech.AudioFormat;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Threading;

namespace DefaultInput
{
    class Program
    {
        // Indicate whether asynchronous recognition has finished.  
        static bool completed;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("fr-CA")))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Culture: {0}", recognizer.RecognizerInfo.Culture.ToString());
                // Create and load the exit grammar.  
                GrammarBuilder gramBuild = new GrammarBuilder("exit");
                gramBuild.Culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
                Grammar exitGrammar = new Grammar(gramBuild);
                exitGrammar.Name = "Exit Grammar";
                recognizer.LoadGrammar(exitGrammar);

                // Create and load the dictation grammar.  
                Grammar dictation = new DictationGrammar();
                dictation.Name = "Dictation Grammar";
                recognizer.LoadGrammar(dictation);

                // Attach event handlers to the recognizer.  
                recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(SpeechRecognizedHandler);
                recognizer.RecognizeCompleted += new EventHandler<RecognizeCompletedEventArgs>(RecognizeCompletedHandler);
                Console.WriteLine();

                // Assign input to the recognizer.  

                //recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

                recognizer.SetInputToAudioStream(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\pgirard\Documents\Enregistrements audio\Enregistrement2.wav"), 
                    new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(44100, AudioBitsPerSample.Sixteen, AudioChannel.Mono));

                //recognizer.SetInputToWaveFile(@"C:\Users\pgirard\Documents\Enregistrements audio\Enregistrement4.wav");



                // Begin asynchronous recognition.  
                Console.WriteLine("Starting recognition...");
                completed = false;
                recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

                // Wait for recognition to finish.  
                while (!completed)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(333);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void SpeechRecognizedHandler(
          object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  Speech recognized:");
            string grammarName = "<not available>";
            if (e.Result.Grammar.Name != null &&
              !e.Result.Grammar.Name.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                grammarName = e.Result.Grammar.Name;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("    {0,-17} - {1}",
              grammarName, e.Result.Text);

            if (grammarName.Equals("Exit Grammar"))
            {
                ((SpeechRecognitionEngine)sender).RecognizeAsyncCancel();
            }
        }

        static void RecognizeCompletedHandler(
          object sender, RecognizeCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  Recognition completed.");
            completed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, .NET is not mandatory. I am more than weeling to go to python or other language that would be more efficient for speech recognition. 
.NET is just the easier giving my company policy.

Answer (score 0):

I did find the source of my problem.
It appear that even if my settings are right, the vocal package in the config pannel / voice recognition / Advence options is still in fr-FR and i am not allowed to change it.

So the SpeechRecognitionEngine use the voice recognition package installed in the Config pannel instead of what it's in the settings.

So i am either gonna deal with it or find another service to do it.

Here's a picture of what it look like: (sorry for french)
[image: Config pannel]